# How can I create a video with certain codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, codec

I am currently testing a video player with DASH contents and I need to create a certain content with two video tracks: one with parameter `@codecs = "avc1.4D4028"` and the other one with value `@codecs="avc1.4D401F"`.

After searching for a while I found out this videos are H.264 with `main profile`.
I have been able to create content with `@codecs=avc1.4d481f` by using this command:

```bsh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $IN_VIDEO \
-c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 3.1 $DIR/vid264.mp4


packager \
input=$DIR/vid264.mp4,stream=video,init_segment=$OUTDIR/vid-a-init.m4a,segment_template=$OUTDIR/vid-\$Number\$.m4a \
--generate_static_mpd \
--mpd_output $OUTDIR/manifest.mpd
```

Also any explanation on those `@codecs` values would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`4D4028` is 3 8 bit integers. First is the profile 66 = baseline, 4d = main, and 64 is high. There is a handful of others.

The next byte is a series of constraint flags. Each bit has a different meaning, (sometimes depending on the profile) and is used to enable/disable some features of the encoder.

The last byte is the level multiplied by 10, and converted to hex. For example 3.1 = 1f. The level is an indication of how complex the stream is in terms of macroblocks per second, and maximum bitrate, the full table is on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels)

Now here is the bad news. You don't really set these values manually. They are usually calculated automatically by the encoder depending on the input settings and video that you are encoding. For example level is automatically calculated via a depending on the resolution, frame rate and desired bitrate. You can override this value but doing that is incorrect in 99% of cases. (choosing a value to low will break a lot of decoders, too high and decoders may reject the video as unsupported)

So, if you want force that exact codec string you must adjust the source video video restitution/frame rate and encoder presets to force the encoder to use the values you want.

Comment: So I cannot set those flags manually?  Should I then try with different video configurations? (Resolutions, bit rates....)

Comment: I would start by targeting the level. Calculate a resolution and frame rate form that table in Wikipedia. The constraints will be harder (and less important to get rite)

Answer (score 0):

It's H.264 Main level 4.0 according to https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media .

The [MPEG-4 Part 10 standard H.264](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/20776/h-264-high-profile-codec-video.html) has [Profiles](http://blog.mediacoderhq.com/h264-profiles-and-levels/) which denote the capabilities of each Profile.  Those Profiles have multiple [Levels](https://www.vocal.com/video/profiles-and-levels-in-h-264-avc/) within, commonly labeled Baseline, Extended, Main, and High.

Baseline's used for portable devices (phones).
Main gives you SD quality.
High gives you HD.

Level numbers within each named level give you higher resolution and frame rates.

Multiple different encoding methods which are available in specific Profiles, Levels, and level Numbers yield different results; a video recording engineer might select a specific combination to get the best results when encoding a video.  Please remember that in video, like in computing, the wonderful thing about standards is that *we have so many of them*.